# Hosting Data for Excel Users

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, asp.net-web-api, data-sharing

researching options here...

I have a C# (winforms) application which allows users to enter some data into a SQL database.  There are two SQL server database locations Americas(2012 v10)/Europe(2014 v11) and the tables are merge replicated.

The structure is relatively simple, one table with some relational selector tables.  However a flat *view* can be created, essentially making the data a single table.

The app has several .rdlc reports included but, I simply don't have the time to create new reports for users every time they ask for them.

Therefore...

I would like to host the data in some format that users can hook up to it with Excel (only tool they are familiar with) and have a current active connection to the live data.  In this way, the users can create their own reports.

The only option I am opposed to is allowing the users to connect to SQL server via ODBC.

I could create a web-api interface and allow the users to connect their Excel to that but, that seems a bit top heavy.

Are there any other (i.e. better) options?

I have also read a bit about OLAP cubes but, this seems a bit heavy as well.  If I need to go with one of the web-api or OLAP options, that's fine.  Just want to make sure I'm not missing out on any other good options.

Thanks

Comment: A web service that returns the data is probably the most straight forward approach here. Since you don't want to use a direct connection there is not many other options. And using an OLAP cube would still require a direct connection but it would be the cube instead of your OLTP database.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll start down that route.  Thanks